# Cross object value

Tags: apex, class

I need some help with getting some object values..
I have a custome object called Named_user__c and a field on that object called Branch__c.. this object contains name, etc just like user object..

On my opportunity object, there`s also a picklist field called Branch__c..

What I wanted = can I select my Named_user__c.Name where Branch__c = opportunity branch?? .. there`s no lookup relationship to opportunity

this is what I`ve tried so far (for my email reminder)

```
global class SchReminderOpportunity implements Schedulable  {


public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 9 * * ? *';
global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlValue FROM EmailTemplate WHERE developerName = 'ET_Opportunity_Reminder'];

    Date now = Date.today();
    String subject = 'Testing Reminder';                            
    String htmlBody = et.HtmlValue;


    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();                   
           htmlBody += '<br><table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr><th><b>Opportunity Name</b></th><th><b>Branch</b></th><th><b>Opportunity Ammount</b></th><th><b>Current Stage</b></th><th><b>Contract Number</b></th><th><b>No. Kerjasama</b></th> <th><b>Opportunity Owner</b></th> <th><b>Description</b></th> <th><b>Detail</b></th></tr>';

           for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name, Name, Description, StageName, Amount, CloseDate, CreatedDate, OwnerId, Owner.Name, Owner.Email,
                            ContractId, Nomor_Kerjasama__c, Contract_No__c, Branch__c FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName != 'Cancelled' AND CloseDate >= :now ]){

                Date oppCloseDate = opp.CloseDate;                
                String dayDiff = String.valueof(now.daysbetween(oppCloseDate));  

                    if (dayDiff == '15'){
                    String oppId = String.Valueof(opp.id);
                    String oppName = opp.Name;
                    String branch = opp.Branch__c;
                    String oppAmount = String.valueOf(opp.Amount);
                    String currentStage = opp.StageName; 
                    String contractNo = opp.Contract_No__c; 
                    String noKerjasama = opp.Nomor_Kerjasama__c; 
                    String owner = opp.Owner.Name; 
                    String description = opp.Description; 

                    htmlBody += '<tr><td>' + oppName + '</td><td>' + branch + '</td><td>' + oppAmount + '</td><td>' + currentStage +  '</td><td>' + contractNo +  '</td><td>' + noKerjasama +  '</td><td>' + owner +   '</td><td>' + description + '</td><td><a href="https://cs72.salesforce.com/' + oppId + '">Click Here</a></td></tr>';   

                    }


        }
    htmlBody += '</table><br><br><br><p>Thankyou,</p><br><p>System Administrator</p>';   
    //
    List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();                        
    for (Named_User__c us : [SELECT Id, Name, Profile__c,Email__c FROM Named_User__c 
                             WHERE Profile__c = 'Marketing']){

        htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!User.Name}', 'Staff');
        SendTo.add(us.Email__c);  
        //mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
    }

    for(string sendToEmail : sendTo){

    if(sendToEmail != null){

    system.debug('===strOwnerEmail===='+sendToEmail);


    //String [] toaddress= New String[]{'rieftjong95@gmail.com'};
    //mail.setTargetObjectId(sendTo);
    mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Administrator');
    mail.setSubject(subject);
    mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);

    List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();    
    ccTo.add('rieftjong95@gmail.com');
    mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);

    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    mails.add(mail);

    }
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you not do something: select my Named_user__c.Name where Branch__c IN (select Branch__c FROM Opportunity where <filter>)

Comment: @αΥβ I tried this before and got this error "semi join sub selects can only query id fields, cannot use: 'Branch__c'"

Comment: ok....I think then only option to make two queries.  first on oppty, prepare a set of branch and then make one more query on custom object with filter using that set....

Comment: @αΥβ you're right there. If there's no shared reference field and no relationship, you're not going to be able to do this in a single query.

Comment: Im a little bit confused.. for example, Oppty branch "UK" will send the email to NamedUser Profile "Marketing" and Branch "UK".. Oppty "US" will send the email to NamedUser Profile "Marketing" and Branch "US".. can I do that without lookup relationship?.. if I make 2 queries and make a set of branch and then filter the NamedUser using that set of branch, the output = all of those NamedUser, even they`re in different branch, will get the same email right?